# Jsoup how to parse text inside span class="hps"

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

```
<span id="result_box" class="short_text" lang="es">
  <span class="hps">
    hello
  </span>
  <span class="hps">
    world
  </span>
</span>
```

I want to get the hello world String using Jsoup but i have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jsoup.parse to get the html Document. Select the elements that you want using css selector like: span.hps (http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<span id=\"result_box\" class=\"short_text\" lang=\"es\">\n" +
                "  <span class=\"hps\">\n" +
                "    hello\n" +
                "  </span>\n" +
                "  <span class=\"hps\">\n" +
                "    world\n" +
                "  </span>\n" +
                "</span>");

    System.out.println(doc.html());

    Elements els = doc.select("span.hps");
    for(Element e:els){
        System.out.print(e.text());
    }
```

In case you don't care about each element value you can replace the for loop:

```
els.text()
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer but still not working :/

Comment: @AntonioCarmona do you have an exception?

Comment: Your code is working but when I'm trying vs the website don't return me the string..

Comment: @AntonioCarmona url of the website?

Comment: let me show you what I'm doing I'm trying to parser the google translator site... when i connect to url i pass this adress.. https://translate.google.es/#en/es/hello%20world   if I analyze the dom tree with firefox i can see the span class = "hps" and the content... but with the jsoup I can't see any result @user1121883

Comment: that translation is displayed after page load using javascript/ajax; so the html that you are feeding into jsoup doesn't contain you text/translation

Comment: Can I have any chance to recover this strings by other methods then? Thank your very much @user1121883

Comment: @AntonioCarmona I think I saw this question many times on stackoverflow. You can try use something that also runs the javascript; like htmlunit.